# Como muestro una imagen de Firebase en Android studio

Tags: java, firebase, imagen

estoy empezando en esto del Firebase y tengo 2 dudas, primero como paso la imagen que tengo en Storage de Firebase al Database para conseguir su "URL"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y segundo, Como muestro la imagen ya cargada al Firebase en mi ImageView??  muchas gracias de ante mano!!!

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String PHAT_START = "start";
    private static final String PHAT_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String PHAT_IMAGENES = "Imagen";

    @BindView(R.id.etMessage)
    EditText etMessage;
    @BindView(R.id.btnSend)
    Button btnSend;
    @BindView(R.id.tvMessage)
    TextView tvMessage;
    @BindView(R.id.Image1)
    ImageView Image1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        final TextView tvMessage = findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(PHAT_START).child(PHAT_MESSAGE);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image1);




      
}
```

Tengo un boton y un TEXT pero lo recorto por que no me deja meter tanto codigo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo tus preguntas, asi que voy a darte un ejemplo completo de como insertar una foto en Storage y en Database. Una vez insertado la foto hay que hacer un método para recoger la Url de Database y ponerla en un ImageView.

1.-Método para insertar una imagen en Storage y Database:

```
 public void addImage(Uri uri){
    //referencia hacia el nodo padre de Storage (NO EXISTE NINGUNA CARPETA), nombre de la foto -->prueba.jpg
    final StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("prueba"+".jpg");
    UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(uri);// insertas la foto en Storage.

    //continuo con la operación para obtener la ruta de Storage
    uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
            }
            return reference.getDownloadUrl(); //RETORNO LA  URL DE DESCARGA DE LA FOTO
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Uri uri = task.getResult();  //AQUI YA TENGO LA RUTA DE LA FOTO LISTA PARA INSERTRLA EN DATABASE
                assert uri != null;
                addImagetodDatabase(uri);  //método para insertar url de la foto en Database

            }
        }
    });
}
```

2.-Como ya tengo la ruta de la imagen, creo un método para insertarla en Database, y llamo a este método en el que acabo de crear en el apartado 1.

```
 private void addImagetodDatabase(Uri uri) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Fotos"); //nodo padre Fotos
    //se generaria de la siguiente forma
    //Fotos:-->id1 { https://......}, id2 {https://......} etc
    databaseReference.push().setValue(uri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                //LA FOTO SE HA SUBIDO A DATABASE CORRECTAMENTE
            }else{
                //ALGO HA FALLADO
            }
        }
    });

}
```

3.-Para poner la imagen en un ImageView te aconsejo utilizar Glide. Te dejo un enlace de como implementar Glide en tu proyecto.

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

4.-Ahora simplemente tienes quea acceder a Database y recuperar la url de la foto, cuando lo tengas, utiliza Glide para poner esa imagen en un ImageView.

```
   Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(urlImage).into(photoImageView);
```

load(urlImage) -->aqui pones la foto que recuperas de database.

into(photoImageView)-->este sería el imageView donde vas a poner la foto.

Espero que te haya servido :)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! no te doy puntos porque esto no me deja, pero una respuesta muy completa